# List of all javascript events sorted by priority

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular

Is there any document online that list all events: keyup, keydown, mouse down, click, focus, focusin, blur, etc. sorted by priority so it can give us some ideas when we are stuck?

We are developing an angular2 app running on chrome browser. Knowing which events is triggered and which one has a higher priority is an asset.

Example: **mousedown** is triggered before **focus** that is triggered before **click** event.

Knowing that, with **mousedown** event, it is possible to determine if the input got the focus from a click or a tab while it was not possible with **click** event because it was processed after the focus, so it is possible customize the focus event with some validation on the mousedown.

Thank you!
Sebastien

Comment: Perhaps the Chrome Inspect/Debugger would be useful for this.  If you switch t o the 'scource' tab, you will find a pane with 'Event Listener Breakpoints' (expand the entry for 'Mouse'.  There you can set  BPs for most events  and see what;s going on when you do mouse things on the page.

Comment: @AdamW that is a good idea! Thank you! Do you know a site where those events are sorted by priority? Like mousedown > focus > click ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp but they are not sorted by priority

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events